# NumberFormatException Android studio crash

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio

My app keeps crashing at the line :

```
   int Price =  (Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getQuantity()));
```

All the ClassAdapter method crashes
I tried changing from '1' to string and other numbers and nothing happened it keeps crashing

Activity:

```
class CartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
  public TextView txt_cart_name,txt_cart_price;
    public ImageView img_cart_count;
    public ItemClickListener itemClickListenerl;
    public void setTxt_cart_name(TextView txt_cart_name) {
        this.txt_cart_name = txt_cart_name;
    }
    public CartViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txt_cart_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_name);
        txt_cart_price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_price);
        img_cart_count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_count);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartViewHolder> {
    private List<Order> listData;
    private Context context;

    public CartAdapter(List<Order> listData, Context context) {
        this.listData = listData;
        this.context = context;
        listData=new ArrayList<>();
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View itemView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_layout,parent,false);
        return new CartViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                .buildRound(""+listData.get(position).getQuantity(), Color.RED);
        holder.img_cart_count.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        Locale locale  =new Locale("en","US");
        NumberFormat fmt  =NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        int Price =  (Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getQuantity())) ;//error line
        holder.txt_cart_price.setText(fmt.format(Price));
      holder.txt_cart_name.setText(listData.get(position).getProductName());  
    }    
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }
}
```

logcat:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1"
>               at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
>               at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
>               at com.OverRout.app.ViewHolder.CartAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CartAdapter.java:72)
>               at com.OverRout.app.ViewHolder.CartAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CartAdapter.java:46)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 " at

You can see that there is an space after the "1"?

All you need to do is add .trim() at the final of your method that gets the string.

The trim removes all spaces in front and after the string, so if you had "   1", after the trim you'll have "1".

Comment: The methods that you use to get strings are this:

Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getPrice()
Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getQuantity() 

Right?

You tried like this: Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getPrice().trim()?

Comment: yup, I did that

Answer (score 0):

.trim() will help you, the String "1 " has an empty space